# Which Meditation Techniques Correlate Best with Certain Brain-Waves?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, brain-training, meditation, brain-waves

***Which meditation techniques are better at "entraining(?)" specifically desired brainwaves?***

For each brainwave range, (Alpha, Theta, etc) - are certain meditative technique more effective?

For example, I was recently told that "Kundalini" was most effective towards Theta Waves, and Mindfulness more effective towards Alpha-Waves...

I had found this, but does the research indicate that some meditative techniques are actually more effective at generating "high amplitude oscillations" for each brainwave range? ...

> **[EEG Derived Neuronal Dynamics during Meditation: Progress and Challenges](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4684838/)**
>
> > **2.1.1. Zen Meditation** - 
> >     Zen meditation, a type of Buddhist meditation, is characterized by increase in slow alpha power, reflecting more internalized attention, and fast theta power, reflecting enhanced mindfulness in frontal area [9, 13]. Long-term practitioners show alpha1 rise in frontal region and beta rise over occipital regions [14].
> >
> > **2.1.2. CHAN Meditation** - Researchers correlated occipital alpha wave rise during eye closed relaxation and frontal alpha wave (representing mindfulness) during CHAN meditation
> >
> > **2.2. Transcending Meditation (TM)** - Various physiological and neural effects in long-term Jacobson's Progressive Relaxation (PR) meditators (a classical method of relaxation), TM meditators, and group of beginners in PR were recorded [28]. Rare theta activity (5–7 Hz) was observed in all the three. ... Higher alpha1 and beta1 reflect automatic self-transcending and open monitoring, respectively.
> >
> > **References**
> >
> > [9] Takahashi T., Murata T., Hamada T., et al. Changes in EEG and autonomic nervous activity during meditation and their association with personality traits. *International Journal of Psychophysiology*. 2005;55(2):199–207. doi: 10.1016/j.ijpsycho.2004.07.004.
> >
> > [13] Chang K.-M., Lo P.-C. F-VEP and alpha-suppressed EEG-physiological evidence of inner-light perception during Zen meditation. *Biomedical Engineering: Applications, Basis and Communications*. 2006;18(1):1–7. doi: 10.4015/s1016237206000026.
> >
> > [14] Huang H.-Y., Lo P.-C. EEG dynamics of experienced Zen meditation practitioners probed by complexity index and spectral measure. *Journal of Medical Engineering and Technology*. 2009;33(4):314–321. doi: 10.1080/03091900802602677.
> >
> > [28] Warrenburg S., Pagano R. R., Woods M., Hlastala M. A comparison of somatic relaxation and EEG activity in classical progressive relaxation and transcendental meditation. *Journal of Behavioral Medicine*. 1980;3(1):73–93. doi: 10.1007/bf00844915.

*Are there any other studies like this that speak to this question?*

Comment: Hi, welcome at CogSci. Have you done some initial research yourself which you could share with us?

Comment: Hi, waiting for some sources, otherwise I'll be voting to close this question.

Comment: I like the edit - that's good

Comment: I have some experience with mindfulness, vipassana meditation and some other related topics. It is known that this subject is not clear, can be consulted https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26441373. I like the topic and I find the question interesting, but I do not think that a clear answer can be offered.